# Deserialization of changed class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, deserialization

I am working on a program, where I save it's project files by serializing Project class.
Because I am still working on it, some classes, that are part of Project class, do change from time to time (e.g. class got new property). It makes "simple" deserialization impossible.

Is there any way to solve it ? I mean, without writng custom serializer ? (which probably is something high above my level for now)

Just in case, I am using BinaryFormatter.

Comment: If the changes weren't so frequent, I would suggest you implement versioning.  I don't know if this article is the best way to help with that, since it is so old, but it might be a place to look - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.80).aspx - also, not sure versioning will help you if you keep changing the format.

Comment: Maybe creating a way to reproduce your artifacts would be good.  Some might say that if you can't script something, you shouldn't be building it.  I've seen this logic often applied to DBs, and even in that case there is *some* way to get your data back out.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham
I am building it to test it. Saved project which helped me speed up testing did not deserialize and I started thinking about this as a problem for future - after the release build.

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood.  Then you definitely want to think about versioning, and that article *might* contain some tidbits that could be useful.  It would be easiest if you can add some metadata when you serialize, parse that metadata separately, then use the routine to pull in the data correctly, and upgrade it to match the newer version.  I haven't actually implemented such a scheme, or I'd try to give a more thorough and useful answer :)

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham
he versioning thing won't work for me, but helped me find the solution, so thanks.

Comment: If you have to support two versions of your object types, to support loading both versions, then using namespaces to separate the duplicated types can help.

Comment: You were able to accept now. Please do not edit solution anouncements into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from Merlyn Morgan-Graham's comments I've found solution, that will work for me.

Versioning described in [*Version Tolerant Serialization*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is really good idea, but when I use only [Serializable] attribute.

I forgot to write (my mistake), that I am using ISerializable interface.
I've found, that in deserialization constructor SerializationInfo object has MemberCount property, which solves my problem if I only add new properties/members from time to time. With this information, new members/properties, that can't be deserialized from older file, can be set to default or maybe I can use some prompt form.

Other way here would be using something like assembly version in deserialization, as a first deserialized member. This can solve deserialization problems with more complex class changes.

Either way, I agree with Merylin - "if you can't script something, you shouldn't be building it". ;)

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. You have a class serialized to a file which you have since changed in the program (e.g you have added another property). Now you want to deserialize this class from the file. This is not a problem as long as you have only **added** new properties. They will be ignored by the deserializer. It creates a new instance of your class (that is the reason why serializable classes *have to have a default constructor*) and tries to fill the properties it finds in the stream to derserialize. If you change a property's type or remove a property, you won't be able to deserialize the original file.

One workaround for removing properties is to keep them in the class, but just stop using them in the rest of the program. A workaround for properties that have been changed to a different type could look something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
     int? newProperty;
     [XmlElement("Property")]
     public string OldProperty 
     {
         get { return string.Empty; }
         set 
         { 
             if (!newProperty.HasValue)
             {
                  int temp;
                  if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
                  {
                       newProperty.Value = temp;
                  }
             }
         }
     }

     public int NewProperty
     {
         get { return newPropery.HasValue ? newProperty.Value : 0; }
         set { newProperty.Value = value; }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I've found using `BinaryFormatter` for serialization/de-serialization of data types that are going to change a really bad idea. If something changes in your data type, from what I know the `BinaryFormatter` will fail in the process.

To overcome this issue in the data types I was using, I had to write my own serializer, which wasn't actually that much of a major task. You can use the [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) classes to read and write the data in and out of your type. That way you can control the data you are expecting and handle any missing data either by adding default values, skipping the property altogether, or throwing some form of `Exception` to signify corrupt data. Refer to the MSDN article links above for more information.